# Master Node(BIP32 Root Key) to xpriv and xpub

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, python, mnemonic-seed, xpub

I struggle to make a python script that can make xpriv and xpub (extended public and private key) from the Master Node (BIP32 Root Key). I've derived the Master Node from the BIP39 seed with passphrase. If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which tutorial are you following? What have you tried so far? What error messages were produced?

Comment: I've now gotten xprivs and xpubs by using bitcoinlib. I want to do it without using a library like bitcoinlib. I want to in the end produce addresses and be able to sign transactions. No tutorial is used as I have not found one.

Comment: Do you intend to implement the key derivation described in the https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki description?

Comment: Yes sir. Hardened addresses.

Comment: I wish you good luck. I'm not sure what your actual specific problem or question here is but presumably you'll post code when you hit a problem that you'd like help with.